# Definition of the limit and value of the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Let's say, as an example:

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2 -25}{x-5}$$

for $ 0<|x-5|<\delta$

$$f(x) = x+5$$ as $x->5$

then we should say, $f(x) -> 10$ , not $f(x)=10$

If $f(x)$ really only approaches $10$, then why in the epsilon-delta definition of the limit, we prove that

$$|f(x)-10|<\epsilon$$

Doesn't this mean that $f(x)$ **equals** $10$ for $ 0<|x-5|<\delta$  ?

Even though $f(x)$ never actually reaches $10$ ?

In short, how is the statement $|f(x)-10|<\epsilon$   and $f(x) -> 10$ true at the same time?

Comment: Do you think that when $f(x)=x+5$, $x\neq 5$ but $|x-5|<\delta $, you'll have $f(x)=10$ ?

Comment: I believe $f(x)$ will never equal $10$ as long as the domain is restricted to $0<|x-5|<\delta$ , Though the inequality $|f(x)-10|<\epsilon$ insists that $f(x)=10$ which is weird.

Comment: I don't even understand the first sentence. What is $\delta$? What does it mean to say that $f(x)=x+5$ as $x\to5$?

Comment: No, it says that $f(x)$ is very close to $10$ when ever $x$ is very close to $5$ (which is indeed the case). @khaled014z

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos it means since $x$ never reaches $5$, we can just cancel the 'zeroes' up and bottom and end up with $f(x)=x+5$ for $x$ not equal to $5$.

Surb, so my understanding of $|f(x)-10|<\epsilon$ is flawed? Doesn't this inequality say 'The distance between $f(x)$ and $10$ is less than $\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ , which then implies that $f(x)=10$?  Or any inequality in general of the form $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon , \forall \epsilon >0$

Comment: I mean if $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary, doesn't $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ mean that the quantity $|f(x)-L|$ is less than every real positive number, so it must be zero?

Comment: @khaled014z There is no “for all $\varepsilon>0$” there. The inequality $\lvert f(x)-10\rvert<\varepsilon$ simply means that $f(x)$ is between $10-\varepsilon$ and $10+\varepsilon$.

Comment: I've given an answer for this that you should look at. However, one thing that you should never do is to look at parts of a definition without added context. You're picking an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. So, $\epsilon$ is arbitrary but fixed. Then, it cannot be the case that $|f(x) - L|$ is less than every positive real number because I can just set $|f(x) - L| = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and that would satisfy the inequality $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. However, clearly, there are real numbers smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but that means we dropped something out of the definition, when can we and when cannot we do that

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Aren't we given an epsilon, then we pick a delta in order to satisfy the inequality, then say we're given another smaller epsilon, then pick a delta to satisfy and so on and so on, and we can do that for all epsilon $ > 0$ provided that the limit exists?

Comment: That's correct in the sense that I should be able to do that for any $\epsilon>0$ that you give to me. However, what you said earlier was that $|f(x) - L|$ is less than every real positive number, which is not true.

Comment: Well, if I could satisfy $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ For each given $\epsilon$ , $\forall \epsilon >0$ , so like, $|f(x)-L| < 1$ and $|f(x)-L| < 0.1$ and $|f(x)-L| < 0.0001$ , i keep doing that for all epsilons > 0, which means that I can get $f(x)$ as close to $L$ until they equal each other?

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall what the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit really says.

Suppose that $f$ is a function defined on a deleted neighbourhood of $x_0$. Then:

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L \iff \forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: 0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

Notice that $f(x)$ **does not** have to be defined at $x_0$ itself. It has to just be defined on any deleted neighbourhood of $x_0$.

The point of the definition is that the value of the function at the point has no bearing whatsoever on the limit of the function at the point.

Now, if you've noticed, $|f(x) - L|$ really is the distance between $f(x)$ for some $x$ in the deleted neighbourhood and the real value $L$, which is supposedly the limit.

So, the definition really is just saying that if you want the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ to be less than $\epsilon$, you need to make sure that the distance between $x$ and $x_0$ is less than $\delta$, where $\delta$ is something you choose. Of course, the distance between $x$ and $x_0$ is formally expressed as $|x-x_0|$.

In your specific case, you're showing that you can restrict the distance between $f(x)$ and $10$ by restricting the distance between $x$ and $5$. You must realize that $f(x)$ is NOT actually defined at $x = 5$ due to a division by 0.

I hope this assists you in understanding the definition. Please do ask more questions (or hit me in the head if I've misinterpreted what you were asking).

Comment: Ok, so the function is defined on a deleted neighborhood of 5, so the value $f(x)$ takes is only close to $10$ and never actually reaches $10$ , so in symbols, $f(x) \ne 10$

, Yet the inequality $|f(x)-10| < \epsilon , \forall \epsilon >0$ implies that $f(x)=10$ on a deleted neighborhood of 5 somehow

Comment: So when we look at the similar definition of continuity, we get, for $|x-a|< \delta$ , $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon , \forall x$ satisfying $|x-a| < \delta$ , so this really means $f(a)=L$ , now in the limit problem, we have $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$, this doesn't imply $f(x)=L$ for $0<|x-a|< \delta$ ?

Comment: $f(x)$ may or may not be equal to 10 on the deleted neighbourhood of 5. That's not the point. The point is that we're not talking about the value of $f(x)$ at 5. We're considering its values in the deleted neighbourhood of 5. Certainly, if we have a point where $f(x) = 10$, then $|10-10| = 0 < \epsilon$ and any $\delta > 0$ that you pick will do the job for that particular point where $f(x) = 10$. As I've mentioned, $f(x)$ is undefined at $x = 5$.

Comment: I am indeed trying to focus on the values of $f(x)$ in the deleted neighborhood of $5$, I understand that $f(x)$ is only approaching $10$ intuitively, but I can't make sense of that due to the inequality $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ , Why do we have the right to deduce that $f(a)=L$ in the continuity case, but we cannot deduce that $f(x)=L$ , for $x --> a$ ofcourse, in the limit case? [Even though in both cases, they say the exact same thing except that one delta neighborhood is deleted and the other is not]

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0:  |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ , then $f(x_0)=L$ due to that last inequality. Now if $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: 0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ , we reached the same inequality at the end, why not say $f(x)=L$ ?